# How to clear screen using colorama?

Tags: python-3.x, colorama

I am trying to clear my output screen using `colorama`

Code: `print('ESC [ mode J')`

But I don't know how to use.
Please share some examples.

Comment: You can use `import os; os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')` which will work on both windows and linux

Comment: Sorry, but this code is not working in PyCharm Windows 10

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: The compiler shows no error! But the screen is not clear.

Comment: post your code .. can't help you other way.

Comment: print("Hello World")
print('clear screen python output console')

print('ESC [ mode J')

Comment: Try and go through some python tutorial first. Im sure my initial code works but you are using it incorrectly.

Comment: Best Answer!..... By the way... My question was:
How to clear screen using Colorama, Genius!

Comment: So, you should also take some tutorial!

Comment: Colorama is a color output module and clearing output using it would be much less efficient if at all possible. I provided you with easy option and all you do is act silly. As i said .. back to school kiddo.

Comment: Your provided code is only of couple of lines... And I ran it in my PyCharm Windows 10. It did not work. I have been seeing YouTube. But this code of yours is not working. Therefore, went for Colorama... I am sorry if I offended you.

Comment: @Mick_ actually you are the one who is wrong, read the question correctly

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example:

```
import colorama
colorama.init()

print(cr.ansi.clear_screen())
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of how I am using to clear the screen with colorama:

The first thing I do is import these two functions from `colorama.ansi` class and `colorama`:

```py
from colorama.ansi import clear_screen
from colorama import init
```

We are going to use the `init` function to make that the `ANSI` output will output what we want.

```py
init(convert=True)
```

Now, for clearing the screen we'll need to write this code:

```py
print(clear_screen(),end='')
```

This is the full example code:

```py
from colorama.ansi import clear_screen
from colorama import init

init(convert=True)

print(clear_screen(),end='')
```

Hope it worked for you ^^.

Answer (score 0):

Like so:

```
>>> import colorama
>>> colorama.init()

>>> print('\x1b[2J')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `os` module.

```
from os import system
import time
print "I will clear the screen in 2 seconds"
time.sleep(2)
system("cls")
print "*Cleared Screen*"
SystemExit()
```

Answer (score -2):

Why use colorama for clearing the console when that's not the intended use of the module?

What you can do is use the `os` module to do it.

```
import os
clear=lambda: os.system('cls') #defines a function to be called later on wherever you like
```

Call it like so:

```
clear()
```

Comment: @Faran2007 why is Linux relevant? OP mentioned in the comments of the question he is using Windows 10? So why would I give a Linux related answer?

Comment: He said use `colorama`, not `os`

Comment: Yes, I am not disputing that, as you can see I mentioned that clearing the console is not the intended use of the module and gave him a different working answer. However your "downvote because in linux you can't" is uncalled for as there has been no mention to Linux in this thread

Comment: I cannot take back the vote unless you edited some part of your answer.